# using curses.nodelay(True) on raspberry pi gives the following error: AttribureError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nodelay'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to make it so that pressing a key on my keyboard (in this case "a") an LED will light up, then turn off immediately when I let go of that key. This works if I use halfdelay([number 1-5]), but not the way that i would like it to. Using 1 turns off the LED almost immediately after I let go of the key, but there is an annoying flicker at the beginning (LED turns on for a fraction of a second, turns off for a few 10th's of a second, and then stays on continuously). If I use 5 the flicker disappears, but the LED stays on for half a second after I let go of the key. Using 2, 3 , or 4 is like a slider, with 2 behaving mostly like 1 and slightly like 5.

Apparently using nodelay should fix this problem at the cost of processing power, but this doesn't work for me at all giving the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nodelay'
```

here is my code:

````
import curses
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.nodelay(3)
screen.keypad(True)

screen.keypad(True)

try:
    while True:

        char = screen.getch()
        print char
        if char == ord('q'):
            break
        elif char == ord('a'):
            GPIO.output(12,True)

        else:
            GPIO.output(12,False)

finally:
    curses.nocbreak();screen.keypad(0);curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    GPIO.cleanup()```
````

Answer (score 0):

`nodelay` is not a module-level curses function; it belongs to `WindowObject`s.

Try `screen.nodelay()` instead.

Comment: I tried using ```screen.nodelay()``` and it asked of either a True or False value. I tried ```screen.nodelay(1)``` and it kept filling up the terminal with diagonal lines of -1. I also tried ```screen.nodelay(0)``` and it works, but the LED doesn't turn off until I press the enter key. Sorry for formatting, not sure how to make a new line when writing comments